# If div inside div got class add specific style to button

Tags: php, jquery, css, woocommerce

How to change "Add to cart" button position using jQuery? I've got structure like this:

```css
.add_to_cart_button {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9.4%;
  right: -16%;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="big-child sale simple">
    <div class="small-child">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code styles "Add to cart" button position. But if the product is on sale, then this button displays a bit higher then I need, the example is shown in attachment[image: Button Add to cart position if Sale and Normal]

I've tried to use jQuery to fix that situation, but with no success. My code looks like this:

```js
if ($('.grand-parent').find('.sale').length > 0) {
  $('a.add_to_cart_button').animate({
    top: -8.4 + "%"
  }, 0);
}
```

But it changes "top" property for all products, not only for those on sale.
How to change code to display "Add to cart button" in top right corner for various types of products (Sale, variable or simple) without gaps?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use if block, Directly use the selector to target the button in the container.

```
$('.grand-parent .sale a.add_to_cart_button').animate({
    top: -8.4 + "%"
}, 0);
```